# AVAssetExportSession: completion callback not called after export is finished

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am creating a video file with images animated on top of it. I track export progress and status, but after export progress reaches 1.0 completion callback is not called, and export status still equals 'AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting'.

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:movieAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
self.session = exportSession;
[exportSession release];
session.videoComposition = self.videoComposition;
NSString *filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *fileName = [[@"Output_" stringByAppendingString:number] stringByAppendingString:@".mov"];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
session.fileLengthLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
[session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self exportDidFinish];
    });
}];
```

It is actually creating an output file, which is unreadable. What I would like to see is some error message, but `error` property of the export session stays empty.

Comment: So, you do recieve some callbacks with AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting? Do you check for all export statuses?

Comment: I have a repeating timer, which logs `progress`, `status` and `error` properties of the session to the console. But the function `exportDidFinish` in the above code is never called. `status` equals `AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting` after `progress` reaches 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was a problem with the video file itself. I downloaded a sample video `sample_iPod.m4v` from Apple [samples](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425) and everything worked as expected. Strange thing is that both my file and the sample are encoded in H.264. What confused me was that no error was shown - neither in console nor in `error` property of `AVExportSession` object:

> 2013-07-02 12:56:06.521 test[2330:907] Export running - [progress: 0.838969, error: nil]
>
> 2013-07-02 12:56:09.020 test[2330:907] Export running - [progress: 0.932188, error: nil]
>
> 2013-07-02 12:56:11.519 test[2330:907] Export running - [progress: 0.999630, error: nil]
>
> 2013-07-02 12:56:14.023 test[2330:907] Export running - [progress: 1.000000, error: nil]
>
> 2013-07-02 12:56:16.519 test[2330:907] Export running - [progress: 1.000000, error: nil]
>
> ...

Comment: I am getting the same problem but only on IOS7. My file being exported however, is a video file that I generate so the corruption is happening with IOS7. Do you know why the file is being corrupted? I can change the output to a different output file format and it will occassionally work.

Comment: Nope, I have no idea what was the problem with the video file, sorry.